# Borland C++ compilation always fails with "Could not load: tlink.exe"

Tags: borland-c++

I'm asking and answering my own question to find the answer later (and to help anyone stuck using the ancient Borland C++ 5.02 compiler for some reason).

I have Borland C++ 5.02 installed in a 32-bit Windows XP virtual machine, with a BC++ project residing in a folder shared with the host computer (mapped to drive letter `H:` in the VM). The project compiles successfully, but always fails the final step with this message:

```
Could not load: tlink.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My compiler is installed in the usual `C:\BC5` location in the virtual machine, but it turns out that it can't handle project folders on paths that contain spaces in their names. So I copied the project from that shared `H:` drive to `C:\BC5\[project]` and voilà! it compiles and links with no problem. I've also copied the project folder to my virtual machine's root `C:\` and that works as well.